# create mongo container in docker with specific ports

Tags: mongodb, docker

[image: the result that i am looking for]

I need to create a mongo container with port as the picture can anyone help with the appropriate command. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?:

```
docker run -p 27017-27019:27017-27019
```